# Animate JSON data with jQuery/AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, animation

I am trying to build a small page that will display data from a JSON object and have that fade in,animate into place on the page, and then fade out.

I've figured out how to get the data to show up and fade out, but I'm stuck on the animate part. I've enclosed what I have so far.

```
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">    </script>
   <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $("div").ready(function(){
          $.getJSON("url",function(result){
              $.each(result, function(i, field){
                $("div").append(field + " ");
              });
         });
       });
   });

   $( document ).ready(function() {
      $("div").hide().fadeIn(3000).fadeOut(3000);
   });
   </script>
```

Where am I missing the point? I've used jQuery to build AJAX type pages before, just trying to figure out why I can't animate the data when I display it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are animating div before your response try this code:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
       $("div").hide().fadeIn(3000).fadeOut(3000);//hiding
       $("div").ready(function(){
          $.getJSON("url",function(result){
              $.each(result, function(i, field){
                $("div").append(field + " ");
              });
              $("div").hide().fadeIn(3000);//animating
         });
       });
   });
```

[<kbd>DEMO</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/6wHRn/1/)

Answer (score 1):

check this http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_animation1

```
$("div").animate({left:'250px'});
```

Comment: I have tried this, but it doesn't seem to do anything. Been testing it on the w3schools editors and it doesn't move the displayed data at all.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$.getJSON("url").done(function(data){
    $.each(data, function(i, field){ $("div").append(field + " "); });
    $("div").hide().fadeIn(3000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can animate using foll code -

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("div").hide().fadeIn(3000).animate({left:'250px'}).fadeOut(3000);
});
```